# Scroll inside of a fixed sidebar

Tags: css, scroll

I have a fixed sidebar on the left of my site with content that has too much content to display on the screen. How can I make that content scrollable while still allowing the right side to be scrollable?

I think a simple `overflow-y: scroll;` would suffice. I need to have a `max-height` on the sidebar, but setting that `max-height` to 100% does nothing. I'm sure this is a simple code pattern, but my CSS skills have deserted me today.

A simple example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tvysB/1/

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Set the `top` and `bottom` to `0`, so that the sidebar is exactly the same height as the viewport:

```css
#leftCol {
    position: fixed;
    width: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tvysB/2/

Comment: I've trying to get a fixed header/fixed sidebar with scroll content (nav) working for a mobile site, and no luck until I ran across this answer. I wasn't exactly sure how the `bottom:0;` would affect my sidebar, but I thought Why not? Worked like a charm. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ah this is the trick! Instead of height: 100%; - top: 0; and bottom: 0; This is the only way to handle the situation where your side-nav is fixed not to the top of the viewport. If it were, say, 200px from the top, height: 100% would actually make it where the bottom of your side-nav were 200px below the viewport.

Comment: Any solution on hiding the ugly scrollbar when you overflow-y scroll something?

Answer (score 29):

I had this same issue and fixed it using:

```
.WhateverYourNavIs {
      max-height: calc(100vh - 9rem);
      overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

This sets the max height for your nav in a way that is responsive to the height of the users browser and then gives it a scroll when it needs it.

Comment: This is also a great solution for elements that are sticky, that are dynamically generated, and scale with size of window.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `position:sticky`  and want to add a scroll in it, @Marc answer works well adding to it I have added hiding scroll bar functionality
Solution with hiding scroll goes like this

```css
.ContainerElem{
    -ms - overflow - style: none;  /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    scrollbar - width: none;  /* Firefox */
    max - height: calc(100vh - 9rem);
    overflow - y: auto;
}
.ContainerElem:: -webkit - scrollbar {
    display: none;  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A weird behavior i saw is about making a fixed scrollable sidebar.
I tried to implement that with `position: fixed;` and just failed with different setting on `overflow`;
What worked for me was using `sticky` instead of `fixed`:

```
 .main-sidebar{
     min-height: 75rem;
     max-hieght: 100vh;
     position: stick;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container{
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, 20%) 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height: 100%;

@include display(flex);
@include flex-direction(column);
@include justify-content(flex-start);
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```