# Sphinx alabaster theme scroll inside of fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css, scroll, python-sphinx

I have made a sphinx project/documentation (using the alabaster theme) that has a fixed sidebar on the left (containing the TOC), but has too much content to display on the screen. How can I make that content scrollable while still allowing the right side (the main text) to be scrollable separately?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337646/scroll-inside-of-a-fixed-sidebar) which is similar, but only deals with your own website, and not a sphinx alabaster themed documentation.

Comment: Look at the generated HTML and CSS and compare it with a theme that does what you want, maybe sphinx_rtd_theme. Copy the CSS for the features you want into the Alabaster theme.

Comment: One problem is that the CSS in the sphinx_rtd_theme is obfuscated into 1 line, and it is hard to read. I'll try nevertheless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out the solution is hidden on this [github PR](https://github.com/bitprophet/alabaster/pull/114). Create a file named `custom.css` that is in the `_static` folder. Then, in `conf.py`, add this code:

```py
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

What that does is tell sphinx to override the default CSS, allowing you to enter your own CSS. Then, in the `custom.css` file, add this code:

```css
div.sphinxsidebar {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

That code makes the scroll bar appear and is what worked for me. This is what the end result looks like:
[image: Documentation with scroll bar]