# How to add scroll bar to a react component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an app like this. [App image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBtHH.png)
I want to add a scroll bar to the section on left and not the whole page. Scroll the left side keeping the right side fixed. Here is my code.

```
function LeftContent(props) {
const { getRef, onHandleNextButton, onHandleStopRecording, ...restProps } = props;
const matches = useMediaQuery('(max-width:800px)');
const items = [...Array(15)].map((val, i) => `Item ${i}`);
return (
    <Box width={matches ? "100%" : "35%"} flex={1} bgcolor={grey[200]} boxShadow="2px 0px 4px lightgrey" zIndex={1} display="flex" flexDirection="column" overflow-y="scroll">
        <QuestionTrackerBox
            {...restProps}
        />
        <ul>
            {items.map((item, i) => (<li key={`item_${i}`}>{ item }</li>))}
        </ul>
        <div overflow-y="scroll">
        {!matches && <RecordedQuestionsList
            {...restProps}
        />}
        {matches && <VideoInterviewBox
            getRef={(node) => getRef(node)}
            {...restProps}
        />}
        <QuestionInformationBox
            onHandleNextButton={onHandleNextButton}
            onHandleStopRecording={onHandleStopRecording}
            {...restProps}
        />
        </div>
    </Box>
)}

function RightContent(props) {
const { getRef, ...restProps } = props;
const matches = useMediaQuery('(max-width:800px)');
if (matches) return null;
return (
    <VideoInterviewBox
        getRef={(node) => getRef(node)}
        {...restProps}
    />
)}
```

What changes do I need to make?

Comment: `overflow-y` is not a valid html attribute. This would be css instead.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337646/scroll-inside-of-a-fixed-sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add scroll-like

```
<div style={{overflowY:"scroll"}}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using css styles, if you set `overflow-y: scroll` on the scrollable element, you can get a scrollbar, but its only when the element "overflows" aka when the content of the element doesnt fit inside of it anymore

Answer (score 0):

Add these css for a

```
  <style>
 div.ex1 {
  width: 200pxpx;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
 }
</style>
```